# Data formatting in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dataformat

Each "user_id" has multiple observations with distinct “Status” values.

```
user_id        status         score      region
  1001         applied         700    california
  1001         pre_approved    700    california
  1001         Approved        700    california
```

What i am trying to do is having one observation per user_id with flags indicating which "Status" values were observed for the "user_id".

```
user_id    applied_ind  pre_approved_ind   Approved_ind         score      region
  1001           1                 1               1             700    california
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       max(1) filter (where status = 'applied') as applied_ind,
       max(1) filter (where status = 'pre_approved') as pre_approved_ind,
       max(1) filter (where status = 'approved') as approved_ind,
       score, region
from t
group by user_id, score, region;
```